# Why my app size more on iphone than the ipa or App Store

Tags: iphone, ios9

I downloaded facebook app on iPhone 6 and its size 99.0 MB on app store but i'm seeing facebook size is 144.0 MB on my iPhone, i didn't find any logic behind it. So please help me Why the app size is increased on iPhone? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps are compressed when you download them. When you have downloaded them, they are uncompressed on your phone.

Therefore you'll see that the App Store states a smaller size, which is the size you have to download - and the phone states a different, larger size, which is the space it takes up on the disk inside the phone.

See for example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_(file_extension)

It states clearly that apps are delivered as .ipa files from the App Store, and that such a file is compressed (zipped).

Answer (score 1):

IPA is a ZIP file, it will unarchive its content on the device.
it also might cache posts/images/...etc general data , 
try installing fresh build ( do not open the app ) and check the size it takes on your device.

Comment: After fresh installation getting 144.0 MB.

Comment: yeah, looks like compressing the images/files is shrinking its size to 99MB